# TWIG - Remove Everything After Certain Character

Tags: twig

In Twig, I am wondering if it is possible to not render everything after a certain character. For example, if I had the string 'Ironman 3 : Marvel' and I want to strip everything after the semicolon so my string will become 'Ironman 3'. I am wondering if this is possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to do this with some variation of `{{ movietitle|split(':')[0] }}`