# Twig split a string after first specific character as delimiter

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a question with the same scenario as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17304739/6578454), except that it might happen that more than one `_` is in the text.

An example;

```
57b42a0557cdd_Filename_whatever.pdf
```

How can I omit everything up until the first underscore (including the underscore) to keep the rest like `Filename_whatever.pdf`

The random uniquifier can be of a different length, but there will always be an underscore between it and the actual filename.

Like in the mentioned question; `{{ filename|split('_')[1] }}` might work, but what if the actual filename has an underscore?

I want it preferably in twig just for displaying purposes because the complete unique name is used on different parts of the project as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As seen in the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html), `split` also supports the `limit` parameter as `explode`, so you can [do](http://twigfiddle.com/amjwon) :

```
{{ '57b42a0557cdd_Filename_whatever.pdf'  | split('_', 2)[1] }}
{{ '57b42a0557cdd_Filename_what_ever.pdf' | split('_', 2)[1] }}
{{ '57b42a0557cdd_File_name_whatever.pdf' | split('_', 2)[1] }}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I somehow didn't understand that one at first. But now I see what's happening with that 2 as a limit argument. Thank you

Comment: Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

Answer (score 1):

Another option (assuming that the file is part of an entity) is to write a function on the entity that that returns what you want.
For example;

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class MyEntity
{
    // ... other attributes

    private $hashFileName;

    private $cleanFileName;

    // other functions

    public function getHashFileName()
    {
        // as per you example; 57b42a0557cdd_Filename_whatever.pdf
        return $this->hashFileName;
    }

    public function getCleanFileName()
    {
        $withouthash = explode('_', $this->hashFileName,2);
        return $withouthash[1];
    }
}
```

Then in your twig file;

```
{{ myObject.cleanfilename }}
```