# in twig file after split the value

Tags: twig

in twig file after spliting the value  i'm getting output like this in a browser

```
<select class="form-control" id="eventCustomerID" name="eventCustomer">
    <option value="64" name="64">64</option>
    <option value="demou22_6hhh" name="demou22_6hhh">demou22_6hhh</option>
</select>
```

but i need an output to be like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="eventCustomerID" name="eventCustomer">
    <option value="64" name="64">demou22_6hhh</option>
</select>
```

this is my code in a twig file

```
<select class="form-control" id="eventCustomerID" name="eventCustomer">
    {% set tags = 64|demou22_6hhh|split('|',1) %}
        {% for x in tags %}
            <option value="{{ x }}" name="{{ x }}">{{ x }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I am stuck with this can someone  help me out with this issue.

Comment: Do note that your snippet contains a syntax error and won't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your required output, you shouldn't use a `for` loop, but access the elements directly.

```
<select class="form-control" id="eventCustomerID" name="eventCustomer">
    {% set tags = "64|demou22_6hhh"|split('|') %}
    <option value="{{ tags[0] }}">{{ tags[1] }}</option>
</select>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/dy5pjg)

---

*Note about the second argument you are passing to the filter `split`*

Not sure why you are passing `1` as the second argument. By setting this parameter to `1`, you are limiting the output to one element in the array. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992935/twig-split-a-string-after-first-specific-character-as-delimiter).